# gtk_widget_add_accelerator with no GdkModifierType

Tags: c, gtk3, gdk

I'm trying to add an accelerator to a "Play" GTK+ 3.0 menu item using the following C code:

```
gtk_widget_add_accelerator(play, "activate", accel_group, GDK_KEY_F5, NULL, GTK_ACCEL_VISIBLE);
```

I want the "Play" menu item to be activated when the user presses the **F5** key. However, when I try to compile I get the following error:

```
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkwidget.h:504:9: note: expected 'GdkModifierType' but argument is of type 'void *'
```

I don't want to add a modifier, just have the menu item activate when the user presses the **F5** key. I realized that I can pass a `0` as the argument (since `GdkModifierType` is just a binary mask), but is there a preferred way over this solution -- perhaps a preprocessor macro called `GDK_NONE_MASK` or something to that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right, you're not supposed to pass *pointers* (e.g. `NULL`) to an `enum` parameter. Attempting to do so is wrong, and this is what the compiler told you.

You can get away with `0`. Implicit conversion from ints to enums will kick in.

To be more explicit, you can write `(GdkModifierType)0` as the argument.

Comment: Is the expression `GdkModifierType(0)` a C++ specific cast?

Comment: @VilhelmGray Correct. `(GdkModifierType)0` would be appropriate for plain C.